# How do I split the Data in Excel file into 2 files using ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have Excel Sheet with Data of ManufactureName, ManufacturePN, RequiredData.
I need to split it into 2 files with the same template based on ManufactureName

```
ManufactureName        |  ManufacturePN       | RequiredData
---------------------------------------------------------
Abracon LLC.           | ABM7-12.000MHZ-D2Y-T | Need Fab & Ic assembly Site
Abracon LLC.           | EMK11H2H-26.000M TR  | Need IC assembly Site
Abracon LLC.           | EMK11H2H-26.000M     | Need IC assembly Site
Allegro MicroSystems   | A3946KLPTR-T         | Need Fab & Ic assembly Site
```

The required output need 2 separate files with the same template one for  Abracon LLC. Company and the other for Allegro MicroSystems

The User will upload 1 file and will download 2 files

Comment: Does [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xME6.png) show the result you want? From the image and the previous data source, it seems that the data is not matched, (such [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j7ho.png)), is here have some logic to divide the excel sheet into two files?

Comment: Yes you're right, The image is wrong, the logic to divide based on companies